# Sort file size limitations and speed

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, what is the maximum file size that one could use in a sort operation? Are there any known stats on performance?

Comment: Thanks for the downvoting, but what does the downvoting tell me exactly?

Comment: [`sort`](http://ss64.com/nt/sort.html) will create temporary files if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell should be able to open and sort any file that NTFS supports.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)

> The maximum theoretical file size on NTFS is 16 EB (16 × 10246 or 264 bytes) minus 1 kB or 18,446,744,073,709,550,592 bytes. With Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, the maximum file size implemented is 256 TB minus 64 KB or 281,474,976,645,120 bytes.

So in theory, Powershell should be able to open and sort any file up to the max file size.  However at its maximum possible size, with CPU, disk, and memory limitations... the speed would be unknowable - and more likely, not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope you are correct. The only reference I found to size was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385611/sort-very-large-text-file-in-powershell and I guess the sort is performed in RAM, and not using external sort (sort chunks then merge). I will accept the answer after some more research, thanks again.